# About I/O Usage in magento2.2

Tags: magento2.2

In magento2.2 and PHP 7.1

When I am using admin my I/O Usage is so high I get 500 error.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can Please describe in brief?

Comment: That's when I'm using an administrator,my server I/O Usage is very high,and then can't open the page.need to restart the server. @AmitBera